# JSON inline edit for mysql table

Tags: mysql, json, html-table, inline-editing

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url="json.php";
    $("#tablo1 tbody").html("");
    $.getJSON(url,function(data){
        $.each(data.members, function(i,user){
        var tblRow =
            '<tr>'
                +'<td class="inlineEdit">'+user.id+'</td>'
                +'<td class="inlineEdit">'+user.firstname+'</td>'
                +'<td class="inlineEdit">'+user.lastname+'</td>'
                +'<td class="inlineEdit">'+user.adres+'</td>'
                +'<td class="inlineEdit">'+user.city+'</td>'
                +'<td class="inlineEdit">'+user.state+'</td>'
                +'<td class="inlineEdit">'+user.zip+'</td>' 
                +'<td class="inlineEdit">'+user.phone+'</td>'
                +'<td class="inlineEdit">'+user.email+'</td>' 
                +'<td class="inlineEdit">'+user.source+'</td>'              
            +'</tr>' ;
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#tablo1 tbody");
        });
    });
});
```

inline edit does not run why ?

When I use this:

```
    $(tblRow).appendTo("#tablo1 tbody").find('.inlineEdit').editable( … ) ;
```

When I use this code  it can not list all entry in db.

Answer (score 0):

tblRow is a javascript var. I think you can not use it inside the $() call.

check out the docs, [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)